# Cannot enable CORS with Spring and Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat

Im running my tomcat 7 server at localhost:9090 and xampp is running on port 80. I want to make a PUT request (with jQuery) from port 80 to my REST-API (Spring 4.2.2) on port 9090.

I get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:9090/rest/location/8609d865-d87a-4340-ab87-0e7f90a6fda9.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
>   The response had HTTP status code 403.

After googling I found several solutions - but none of them worked.

**What I tried:**

-Add a filter to web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

-Add annotation to my controller

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class LocationController
```

-Add a header to my responses

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
```

-Add a OPTIONS route

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**", method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity options(@PathVariable String locationID) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
}
```

None of them worked for me, I'm still receiving the error above. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done it in my current project:

- Added following dependency in `pom.xml`

`<dependency>
            <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>`

- Added following filter into `web.xml`

`<filter>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>`

- Added filter-mapping to the top of the filter-mapping list

`<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>`

Notice that I explicitly added `PUT` as supported method.

The only downside of this approach is the additional dependency.

`spring-web` has its own implementation of CORS filter (`org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter`). I'm sure that it is possible to configure the spring's one in the same way.